# Maxicode maximum data lengths with compression

Tags: barcode, ups

I have been looking at the output of a decoded UPS Maxicode and noticed that the number of characters go past the maximum data length according to [this online generator](https://products.aspose.app/barcode/generate?type=maxicode). After testing it repeatedly across multiple maxicodes, I found that all of them went past the codetext capacity. I was under the impression that Maxicode data encoding was lossless? Is there an additional layer of compression that is necessary to recreate a standard input length?

I used the following [generated Maxicode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cpG4c.png) from Shippo, the decoded string is below.

> [)>01969174800008400031Z94300000UPSN39Y1F007A0OOI4C%"JD*R%Y:Y/FKQ/+:E6AF0+A(,"IG&:KZLP

Using methods 2 and 3 for Maxicode encoding, all prove to be out of range.

Answer (score 0):

Maxicode uses 6-bit code words, meaning a given code word can encode a value between 0 .. 63.  In order to represent 8-bit character values, there are five different character sets A .. E that contain all possible 8-bit values (with some overlap between sets).  To encode an "unstructured" message, each character in the message is mapped to one of the five character sets.  Each time there is a change in character set, a latch or toggle control word is added to indicate which character set is now active.  It is those extra control words that limit (reduce) how many 8-bit character values can be encoded in a single symbol.

The message you show above is what the maxicode spec refers to as a "structured" message and uses only character set A. Using a single character set allows approximately 124 characters to be encoded since there is no added overhead of switching character sets.

Comment: The text formatter ignored the nonprintable characters in my maxicode data (there are 86 characters with set A, but with the escaped characters, it's 98). I suspect that the characters with the values `'\x1c'`, `'\x1e'`, `'\x1d'`, and `'\x04'` are the issue? It still doesn't explain how maxicode encoders are limited to 93 characters, when the output includes these characters and that my other tests show an average of 98 characters total.

Comment: Hi ,I think if you have only numbers in MaxiCode data it can hold more characters. Probably like Mark said, you ca store up to 124 numeric characters. If you want to be certain, because you have various types of characters, you should probably limit your length to 93, like it was recommended on this page https://www.cognex.com/resources/symbologies/2-d-matrix-codes/maxi-codes . I use their app to check my printouts.